# Save HTML form data to text file using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using node js and my requirement is  save HTML form values which is sent by user, and store those values in text file using node js, and each time data should be save to next lines instead of saving to same line.I got stuck how to do this process.

HTML Code:

```
<form method="POST" action="/users/contact"> 

  <select name="car" size="1"  required id="rankx">
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Option</option>
    <option value="volvo">volvo</option>
    <option value="swift">swift</option>
  </select>

<br />
  <select name="model" size="1"  required>
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Rank</option>
    <option value="c500">c500</option>
    <option value="Ta66">Ta66</option>
  </select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit"/>
```

Node js Code:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var fs = require ('fs');
     
       router.post("/contact",function(req,res){ 
   
    let car = req.body.car;
    let model = req.body.model;
    var form_data = {
        car: car,
        model: model
    }
  fs.appendFileSync('./message.txt',form_data.toString()); 
  });
```

Required outpt: // store in text file userData.txt
id carname  carmodel
1   abc      abc_1
2   xyz      xyz_1

Comment: You're passing a callback function to appendFile**Sync**. Please always check the docs first.

Comment: "*I got stuck how to do this process*" is not a helpful problem statement. Where *specifically* are you getting stuck? What's wrong with the code you've posted here? Can you refactor the code you've provided here to meet the standards of a [mre]?

Comment: @ChrisG yes I just want to check errors and show to console.

Comment: @esqew  actually I got stuck at  storing  data in text file

Comment: What do you mean by "yes"? Did you look at the docs yet? https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsappendfilesyncpath-data-options

Comment: @ChrisG just now  I observe for async function no callback function should be placed, can u mention or write down the few lines of code to store form values in text file.

Comment: @user_1234 Have you done any research before asking others to write your code *for* you? Extracting values from form data in Express and writing values to a text file in Node are two fundamental topics which have been asked here and elsewhere around the Internet time and time again.

Comment: @esqew I tried it and wasted my 2 hours still unable to do, thats the reason I have asked it.

Comment: In your node.js code you are using `router` , but where is that router declared?
I just see express imported but not initialized

Answer (score 0):

The solution what happens to me was first create a JSON file to save the data and next put this information in a text file. Following four steps:

Step 1: First you need read the existing data from JSON file.

Step 2: Add new car using push method.

Step 3: Write the new and old data in JSON file.

Step 4: Write the new info in the a text file.

Here is the code:
app.js

```
const express = require('express'); 
const app =express()
var fs = require ('fs'); 

// middleware  

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true})) 

// STEP 1: Read the existing data from json file  

let users= require("./message.json")

// API routes 

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
  }) 
     
app.post("/",function(req,res){ 
   
    let car = req.body.car;
    let model = req.body.model;
    
    // new car 
    let formData = {
        car: car,
        model: model
    } 

    res.send(formData)  

    // STEP 2: add new user data to users object using push method  
   users.push(formData) 

   // STEP 3: Writing data in a JSON file 

   fs.writeFile('message.json', JSON.stringify(users), err =>{ 
     if(err) throw err 

     console.log("Done writting JSON file")
   }) 

   // STEP 4: Write the new info in the text file named message

  fs.writeFile('./message.txt',JSON.stringify(users), err =>{ 
    if(err) throw err 

    console.log("Done writting text file")
  }); 
  });  

  app.listen(3000, function(){ 
      console.log("server started on port 3000")
  })
```

You need create a JSON file to save data like this:

message.json

```
[]
```

and a empty message.txt to storage the data, this file overwrite when save the data.
Leave screenshots.
I hope help you.
[image]